# How to rotate x-labels in one subfig?

Tags: r, graphics

When I use `text()` in the following way, the labels will not be shown.

```
layout(
  mat=rbind(
    1
    , 2
    , 3
  )
  , heights=c(5, 1, 1)
)
par(
  oma = c(5,4,0,5)
  , mar = c(0,0,1,0)
)
plot(1:10, 1:10, xaxt='n')
plot(1:10, 1:10, xaxt='n')
plot(1:10, 1:10, xaxt='n')
text(1:10, 0, srt = 60, adj = 1, xpd = T, labels = 1:10)
```

If I just use it alone, then the x labels can be rotated.

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, xaxt='n')
text(1:10, 0, srt = 60, adj = 1, xpd = T, labels = 1:10)
```

How to rotate labels in the first case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `xpd = NA` to prevent the text being clipped to the plotting region in a multi-plot layout, as explained in the docs (emphasis added)

> **xpd**    A logical value or NA. If FALSE, all plotting is clipped to the plot region, if TRUE, all plotting is clipped to the figure region, and **if NA, all plotting is clipped to the device region**. See also clip.

Which means you can do:

```r
layout(
  mat=rbind(
    1
    , 2
    , 3
  )
  , heights=c(5, 1, 1)
)
par(
  oma = c(5,4,0,5)
  , mar = c(0,0,1,0)
)
plot(1:10, 1:10, xaxt='n')
plot(1:10, 1:10, xaxt='n')
plot(1:10, 1:10, xaxt='n')
text(1:10, 0, srt = 60, adj = 1, xpd = NA, labels = 1:10)
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the doc of xpd? I don't see it in ?text.

Comment: If you look at the last entry in the help file for text, it says `... 
further graphical parameters (from par), such as srt, family and xpd.` , which means these arguments are passed to `par`. The entry for `xpd` is in the help file for `?par`